# Não precisa mais em C# usar método, classe, namespace e using?

Tags: c#, .net, característica-linguagem, estilo-de-codificação, asp.net-core-web-api

Vi um exemplo de [Minimal API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) usando .NET e o código era só assim:

```
var app = WebApplication.Create(args);
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.Run();
```

Não era um *snippet*, era todo código. Onde foram parar toda aquela cerimônia que C# sempre teve? Virou uma linguagem de *script*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desde [C# 9 é possível criar códigos sem classes ou métodos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), desta forma fazendo C# tem um jeito de *script*.

A linguagem continua com todas as outras características, o que dificulta para ser usada exatamente como *script*, mas pode ser usada sim, ainda que não seja a mais adequada. Ficou mais fácil especialmente prototipar algo.

Não usar *namespace* sempre foi possível.

Note que isso é só [*syntax sugar*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575689/101). Tá tudo lá, mas não precisa digitar tudo isso.

Na verdade, só em C# é que não precisou usar mais `using` para importar o que vai usar. Também está lá, mas está em um arquivo implícito que o projeto usa. Ele usa uma coisa chamada [`global using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), onde define o que deve ser importado para todo o projeto.

Seu uso é um pouco polêmico porque pode criar alguma dificuldade se importar coisas demais que podem ter conflito com outras coisas da aplicação, mas isso pode ser configurado, existe um arquivo com o que é usado globalmente para não precisar importar em cada arquivo, pode tirar algo que esteja atrapalhando (tecnicamente pode usar a sintaxe em qualquer lugar, mas na prática sempre usará só nesse arquivo "especial").

De fato, um Hello World em C# pode ser criado assim agora:

```
Write("Hello World");
```

Mas para quase tudo o que se faz em C# é bobagem usar isto. C# foi criada para fazer aplicações, então o uso normal não é um problema de sintaxe escrever tudo o que antes era obrigatório.

Padrão para aplicação console:

```
System
System.Collections.Generic
System.IO
System.Linq
System.Net.Http
System.Threading
System.Threading.Tasks
```

Para web ainda tem:

```
System.Net.Http.Json
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/GlobalUsing.cs).