# O que é lowering e desugar?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem, compiladores

Vi estes termos sendo usado em compiladores. Além de querer saber o significado, eles são sinônimos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu espero que alguém consiga dar uma resposta mais definitiva já eu nunca achei nada cravando as diferenças entre os termos.

Até onde eu já vi eles seriam sinônimos, e costumam ser usados intercambiavelmente até mesmo pela mesma pessoa que constrói compiladores. Mas definição canônica nunca vi.

Já vi [documentado que *syntax sugar* foi definido por Peter J. Landin em 1964](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), mas nada sobre *lowering*.

Em alguns casos vi uma diferença que o *lowering* seria apenas uma simplificação em alto nível para códigos normais da própria linguagem, enquanto o *desugaring* seria a transformação para um código base em nível mais baixo, que seria, potencialmente, até inválido na linguagem que está compilando. Mas quase todo mundo chama qualquer transformação em *sugar*, assim *lowering* parece ser um termo mais técnico de quem trabalha com compiladores.

Então o primeiro seria o `for` ou `foreach` virando `while`, ou o `using` (C#) virando `try-finaly`, só para ficar com dois exemplos, e o segundo já seria o `while`, e quem sabe o `for` ou `foreach`, sendo transformado em uma forma de *compare* (`cmp` por exemplo) e pelo menos dois *branches* (`jz` por exemplo).

Se você for a fundo na definição até a variável seria *syntax sugar* já que ela é um [padrão de projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101).

A própria definição de *syntax sugar* não é tão universal, e [há inúmeras discussões](https://wiki.c2.com/?SyntacticSugar) até onde uma sintaxe introduz algo real novo ou é só uma maneira diferente de fazer o que já podia fazer de outra forma. Há até quem pregue que só não é *sugar* se for o código de máquina. Para quem acha que não vai tão baixo nível provavelmente considera os termos como sinônimos.

Também vi algo que poderia indicar que o açúcar sintático é o conceito geral e fazer *lowering* é a técnica específica.

Por curiosidade procurei pelo [termo da técnica no compilador do C#](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/search?q=lowering).

C++ é um caso curioso que era praticamente só *sugar* em cima de C, até que algumas coisas não podiam mais ser assim e precisou um compilador próprio e começou a cisão definitiva.

Existem casos que *sugar* sequer muda algo no código, por exemplo o uso de `_` em literais numéricos como separadores. Algumas linguagens podem permitir escrever alguma palavra extra pela legibilidade que na prática não é necessária.

Na prática ambos, mesmo que não considere como sinônimos, devem permitir mais [expressividade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/563253/101) na linguagem sem adicionar funcionalidade.

Sem entrar nas transformações em outras linguagens e sem fazer uma lista completa, que pode ser infinita, e considerando que algumas linguagens podem ou não fazer *lowering/desugaring* em alguns desses itens, como *loops* por exemplo que podem não ser unificados, mas entrando nos casos que algumas linguagens tratam de maneira diferente e vão além da simples transformação (não quero entrar na discussão, sei que vários casos fazem mais que açucarar na maioria das linguagens, mas poderia ser em alguma implementação/especificação):

- Método é função com um parâmetro a mais
- Propriedade é um par de métodos de acesso e modificação de um campo
- Lambda é ser uma função com [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) e pode ter um estado carregado junto ([*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101))
- Evento é só a aplicação do [Observer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101)
- Inicializador é a chamada de construtor e métodos de manipulação do tipo
- Literal, em alguns casos, é a chamada a um construtor
- Operador (pelo menos sobrecarga) é apenas um método
- Operador composto é só o operador normal aplicado na mesma variável
- Operador condicional é um `if`
- Operador de coalescência é um ternário co mum valor padrão
- Referência é ponteiros com restrições
- Acesso a membro por ponteiro pode ser mais facilmente escrito (`->`)
- Inferência é (ou não dependendo do conceito adotado) só colocar o tipo que o programador não colocou
- Importação de módulos e afins é a maneira de dar contexto para inferência tipos e membros deles usados no código
- Tipagem dinâmica só esconde acesso seguro a uma estrutura complexa de dados
- Tipo anulável (em C#) é só um tipo genérico com um item extra
- ADT é só uma *union* com uma *tag* e quem sabe um parâmetro
- Enumeração pode ser uma forma de uso de constantes
- *List comprehension* é um *loop*
- Tupla ou retorno de função por tupla é uma `struct` com membros anonimizados
- Desestruturação é a escrita de um mapeamento de membros para variáveis
- Assincronicidade é uma forma de [máquina de estados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208328/101)
- Genericidade é a reescrita de tipos e funções com um parâmetro alterado
- Gerador (`yield`) é acesso a um estado  de controle de uma lista de dados
- [LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182176/101) é todo *syntax sugar*

Aceito sugestões.

Um erro comum é achar que um `switch` é só o *lowering* para `if`, e até pode ser em alguma linguagem, mas em gera ele cria uma ou algumas formas mais poderosas. Em alguns casos eles podem fazer análises mais complexas, até mesmo [*pattern matching*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/410484/101). Em muitos casos o operador composto tem funcionalidade diferente. Enfim, em muitos casos a classificação depende da implementação, não tome a lista como algo universal.

É possível ter alguns açúcares sintáticos pela biblioteca, embora raramente se use o termo assim. No fim tudo acaba sendo alguma abstração.

Como curiosidade final há quem fale de açúcar artificial (sacarina, aspartame) quando a pretensa melhoria piora a sintaxe. Também se fala em sal sintático (*syntax salt*) quando algo é feito para dificultar o programador cometer erros, ou seja, não precisa fazer aquilo na linguagem, mas obrigando força ele acertar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).