# O que significam os nomes gerados internamente pelo compilador?

Tags: c#, .net, compiladores, clr

Vendo [códigos gerados pelo compilador](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDNgAinA7Gg3stQjOANgwBY0BZAQwEsA7ACgEo8CjPMY0BjAGwD2AZwCuAJwCmaALxoAKpOEAXVgG4OnQgJETJ6zVp1ipBpJwC+hzGW4KlqtvnNbCjZX0GiGyyeNloAAwaLq5QOKyyAHzEAJxMvF4+fmBgLCGWyBZAA=) tem nomes bem esquisitos com números. O que eles significam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os compiladores frequentemente usam uma técnica chamada [*lowering*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575689/101) que faz um código mais abstrato ficar um pouco mais concreto na própria linguagem. Então ele gera um código para que depois seja compilado como se o programador tivesse escrito.

Quase sempre esses códigos possuem identificadores e não podem colidir com outros nomes já existentes. Evitar isso com o próprio código original a ser compilador é fácil colocando alguma sequência de caracteres reservados que só o compilador pode usar. Mas ainda pode conflitar com códigos gerados ma compilação.

Os nomes dos identificadores costumam ser escolhidos de acordo com a funcionalidade sendo criada. E geralmente os números são sequências dentro da unidade de compilação para garantir que eles serão únicos. Se o identificador precisa ser usado fora da unidade de compilação precisa de uma técnica mais sofisticada para gerar um nome não ambíguo.

Para dar uma base tem um [código que foi usado para gerar esses nomes](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Synthesized/GeneratedNames.cs). Mas hoje já é diferente. No passado usava-se nomes mais mnemônicos do que usa hoje.

Uma tabela anti ga que eu achei:

```
the iterator state ("state")
the value of current in an iterator ("current")
a saved parameter in an iterator
a hoisted 'this' in an iterator ("this")
a hoisted local in an iterator
the hoisted locals from an outer scope
a hoisted wrapped value ("wrap")
the closure class instance ("locals")
the cached delegate instance ("CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate")
the iterator instance ("iterator")
an anonymous method
anonymous method closure class ("DisplayClass")
iterator class
fixed buffer struct ("FixedBuffer")
anonymous type ("AnonymousType")
initializer local ("initLocal")
query expression temporary ("TransparentIdentifier")
anonymous type field ("Field")
anonymous type type parameter ("TPar")
auto prop field ("BackingField")
iterator thread id
iterator finally ("Finally")
fabricated method ("FabricatedMethod")
dynamic container class ("SiteContainer")
dynamic call site ("Site")
dynamic delegate ("SiteDelegate")
com ref call local ("ComRefCallLocal")
lock taken local ("LockTaken")
```

Note que isso tudo não é documentado e pode mudar, não se valha disso para nada no seu código.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).