# Global using do C# está atrapalhando, como desligar isso?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, using

Fui tentar usar o mecanismo relatado em [Não precisa mais em C# usar método, classe, namespace e using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575585/101) e não ficou legal.

Importou *namespace* que eu não queria e causou conflito com o que eu usava.

Pode usar o recurso, mas controlando o que é importado? Ou pelo menos posso não usar, já que agora cria um projeto e ele está lá sempre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão agora novos projetos começam com um arquivo chamado `GlobalUsings.g.cs` onde existem os `global using`s que ele usará. Você pode mudar o que está lá no arquivo (ainda que o mais recomendado seja não mexer diretamente neles.

Pode até mesmo mudar o *template* que é usado para gerá-lo, mas não recomendo fazer, se for o caso crie um *template* novo e passe usar no lugar.

Se quiser que não crie isso pode usar `--use-program-main` no `dotnet` CLI. Ou fazer pelo Visual Studio:

[image: Tela mostrando a opção para desabilitar]

Além disso é possível configurar no projeto que algum deles não devem ser usados implicitamente:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Using Remove="System.Net.Http" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Ou pode desabilitar completamente o uso implícito:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Você pode adicionar também:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="SuperheroApp.Models"/>
    <Using Include="System.Console" Static="True" />
    <Using Include="System.DateTime" Alias="DT" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Via código, pontual e diretamente na hora do uso, não é possível fazê-lo, ainda, pra mim é uma falha.

Algumas pessoas estão adotando este mecanismo só quando vão fazer *scripts* e não para aplicações, outras vão mais fundo.

Conteúdo do arquivo gerado para um projeto Console:

```
// <auto-generated/>
global using global::System;
global using global::System.Collections.Generic;
global using global::System.IO;
global using global::System.Linq;
global using global::System.Net.Http;
global using global::System.Threading;
global using global::System.Threading.Tasks;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/RemoveGlobalUsing.cs).